# How to pass a parameter in php route

Tags: php, routes, twig

I need to edit a row in a datatable , the problem is the edit Modal ,when I use id's I click the edit button,the modal opens and retrieves the data of my table but I can't edit the datas, except the first row of my datatable that I can edit.

when I use classes if I edit the last row of my table it will modify the first row but with the data of the last row.

-> The Controller to get a user by id and edit :

```
$controllers->post('/modif', function (App $app,Request $request) {
        try{
 
        $ListeUser  =$app->service('User')->getUser($request->get('id'));

        $ListeUser->setNom($request->get('nom'));
        $ListeUser->setPrenom($request->get('prenom'));
        $ListeUser->setAdresse($request->get('adresse'));
        $ListeUser->setLogin($request->get('login'));
        $ListeUser->setPassword($request->get('password'));
        $ListeUser->setAcces($request->get('acces'));
        $ListeUser->setArchive($request->get('archive'));
                 
            $app->sauvegarder($ListeUser);
            return new Response('sauvegarde',200);
         
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
             return new Response($ex->getMessage(),400);
             } 
            })->bind('modif')->before($this['loginok'])->before($this['isAdmin']);
```

This is the modal in twig :

```
  {% for user in users %}  
           <div class="modal fade" data-user-id="{{ user.id }}" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modalModifCl">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modifier Client</h4>
            </div>
            
            <!--FORMULAIRE -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- APPEL FONCTION -->
              <form action="{{app.route('modif',{'id':user.id})}}" class="form-horizontal form3" method="post" >
                   
                  <input id="idClient" name="id" type="hidden" value="{{user.id}}">
                   
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="nom">Nom</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="Nom" type="text" value="{{user.nom}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="prenom">Prénom</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" id="prenom" name="prenom" placeholder="Prénom" type="text" value="{{user.prenom}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="adresse">Adresse</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" id="adresse" name="adresse" placeholder="Adresse" type="text" value="{{user.adresse}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="login">Login</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Login" type="text" value="{{user.login}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" type="password" value="{{user.password}}">
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- archive caché-->
                    <input class="form-control" id="archive" name="archive" placeholder="archive" type="hidden" value="{{user.archive}}"> <!-- acces caché-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control" id="acces" name="acces">
                                <option value="2">
                                    Client Prive
                                </option>
                                <option value="3">
                                    Client Pro
                                </option>
                                <option value="1">
                                    Admin
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div><!--BOUTONS FERMER ET VALIDER DANS FORMULAIRE MODIFIER CLIENT-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Fermer</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary validerMod" type="button">Valider </button>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

The jQuery :

```
$(function () {
     /* MODAL Modifier client Privé */
       $('.btMod').click (function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.modal[data-user-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]').modal({
        show:true,
        backdrop:'static'
        });
        });
       
       
       /* MODAL BOUTON VALIDER FORMULAIRE MODIFIER CLIENT PRIVE */
        $('.validerMod').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
        url:$('.form3').attr('action'),
        type: $('.form3').attr('method'),
        data: $('.form3').serialize()
                                                                                                             
        }).done(function(data){
        $('#modalModifCl').modal('hide');
  
        window.location.href='{{app.route('clientsPrive')}}';
        alert("Client modifié avec succès !");                             
                                     
        }).fail(function(data){
        console.log(data.responseText);
        });
        });
});
```

Edit:
Here is the datatable code in twig :

```
    <div class="row" style="  display:flex;  margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto; width:100%; margin-bottom: 5vw; margin-top:1vw;
         border:1px solid #b1e7e7; background:rgba(102, 204, 255, 0.05);"> 
        <div class="col-lg-12" > 
   
           <table id="user" class="display" > 
              
                {%if app.isAdmin %}     
             <button id="bt-{{user.id}}" data-id="{{user.id}}" class="btn btn-primary act btClient" style="background:#0088cc; font-size:0.4vw;" title="Nouveau client">
             <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="font-size:1vw;"></span></button> 
             {%endif%} 
               
            <!-- TABLE USER -->  
            {% for user in users %}  
            <tr> 
                <td> {{user.id}} </td> 
                <td> {{user.nom}} </td>                  
                <td> {{user.prenom}} </td> 
                <td> {{user.adresse}} </td> 
                <td> {{user.login}} </td>                     
                <td> {{user.AccesString}} </td>
                  
                <!--BOUTONS DANS DATATABLE-->
                   
                <td>
                   {%if app.isAdmin %}    
                       
                       <!-- Bouton Details client-->
                       <button style="font-size:0.4vw; background:#0088cc;" class="btn btn-info" title="Détails">
                       <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="font-size:1vw;"></span></button> 
                       
                        <!-- Bouton Ajouter compte client-->
                       <button id="bt-{{user.id}}" data-id="{{user.id}}" class="btn btn-primary act btCpCl" style="background:rgba(0, 136, 204, 0.5); font-size:0.4vw;" title="Nouveau compte">
                       <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="font-size:1vw;"></span></button> 
                       
                       <!-- Bouton Modif client-->
                      <button id="bt-{{user.id}}" data-id="{{user.id}}" class="btn btn-primary act btMod" style="background:rgba(0, 136, 204, 0.5); font-size:0.4vw;" title="Nouveau compte">
                       <span class ="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:1vw;"></span></button> 
                         
                       <!-- Bouton Liste des comptes par client-->
                         <a style="font-size:0.4vw; background:rgba(0, 136, 204, 0.7);" href="{{app.route('listeCp',{id:user.id})}}" class="btn btn-info" title="Liste des comptes">
                         <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" style="font-size:1vw;"></span></a>
                         
                         {%endif%}
                 </td>
            </tr>
           {% endfor%}
    </table>
    </div>    
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm using framework Symfony with Silex

Comment: Also, from what I can derive from your code is that you storing passwords as plaintext. You shouldn't be doing this. Please have a look at [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php)

Comment: How did this question turn from "How to pass a parameter in php route" to what it is now?

Comment: To be more specific about m’y issue

Answer (score -1):

In `Laravel`, which is based on `Symfony`, you would pass parameters in named routes like this

```html
<form 
  method="GET" 
  action="{{ app.route('getuser',['id' => $id ])}}"
>
    
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but the browser says "ErreurUnexpected character "$".

Comment: yeah, you need to replace the variable with your id reference. Maybe `user.id`
`{{ app.route('getuser',['id' => user.id ])}}`

Comment: Hi thanks but the problem was the variable user was unknown, DarkBee was right.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the `user` variable doesn't exist when you are running

`form class="form-horizontal" id="form3" action="{{ app.route('getuser',{'id':user.id})}}" method="get">`

A solution would be to create the modal container for each of your users

```
{% for user in users %}
<div class="modal fade" data-user-id="{{ user.id }}" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modifier Client</h4>
            </div><!--FORMULAIRE -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- APPEL FONCTION -->
                <form action="{{ app.route('getuser',{'id':user.id})}}" class="form-horizontal" method="get" name="form3">
                    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="nom">Nom</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" name="nom" placeholder="Nom" type="text" value="{{user.nom}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="prenom">Prénom</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" name="prenom" placeholder="Prénom" type="text" value="{{user.prenom}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="adresse">Adresse</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" name="adresse" placeholder="Adresse" type="text" value="{{user.adresse}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="login">Login</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" name="login" placeholder="Login" type="text" value="{{user.login}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2" for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" type="password" value="{{user.password}}">
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- archive caché-->
                    <input class="form-control" name="archive" placeholder="archive" type="hidden" value="{{user.archive}}"> <!-- acces caché-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control" name="acces">
                                <option value="2">
                                    Client Prive
                                </option>
                                <option value="3">
                                    Client Pro
                                </option>
                                <option value="1">
                                    Admin
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div><!--BOUTONS FERMER ET VALIDER DANS FORMULAIRE MODIFIER CLIENT-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Fermer</button> <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Valider</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

You could then show the correct modal by adjusting the javascript

```
$('.btMod').click (function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal[data-user-id="'+$(this).data('id')+'"]').modal({
        show:true,
        backdrop:'static'
    });
});
```

---

*sidenote*

Your code is generating a lot of HTML elements with the same `id`, this is not correct and will make your JavaScript not work correctly when trying to refer to these `id`'s.
I **did not** edit out these `id`'s in the code above but you definitely should.

Comment: @superjony I've updated the form without any id's. I was tired the moment I've created this answer, so now I've updated it. You get multiple id's cause the modal is present X times in the HTML.

Comment: So I removed the ids and put classes instead but now I can't edit a row at all, it's strange if I put ids instead of classes I can only edit first row of datatable... Any idea ??

Comment: I dont understand, if I use a twig instead of a modal I can edit all the rows, but when I use a modal it's impossible to edit a row, for example if I edit the last row it will affect the first row

Comment: What am I missing ?